# Asp.net core foreach loop rendering html after _layout.cshtml

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-core-mvc

I have created an asp.net core MVC application using MVC template.
After I added a new model and controller using scaffolding feature.
Inside the Index page, I have a `foreach` loop to show a table with some fields and for this, I am using asp.net helpers.
Everything works fine, but when I debug the application the HTML inside the `foreach` loop is being rendered after the `renderbody()` in _layout.cshtml in the Shared folder.

Any guess what I did wrong?

[image]
dotnet core version: 2.1.200-preview-007474

Comment: do you a GitHub account to show us code.. we are working with brail at present without a properly code snippet example of your work.

Comment: Hi @mvermef I thought that I had deleted this question, but looks like not. Any way, the problem was happening because I didn't close table in HTML. After post the message I take a look in code and see my mistake. Thanks for you feedback.

Answer (score 0):

Actually the error was in the html on the page. I just add the tag to close the table and the page load in correct order.

Thanks.